# execute javaScript on Selenium WebDriver before get() on java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to access a web page using selenium in Java. The problem is that the site is giving me an error 
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined.`
I asked a front end dev and told me that i should try to load a javascript before the loading of the page. The script he mentioned is  `require.js`
and i found it at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js

I am using  `htmlunit-driver 2.28`
I noticed that when I initialise the driver like
`HtmlUnitDriver driver =new HtmlUnitDriver(true);`
I do get an option of
`driver.executeScript(script, args)`
which is not available on `WebDriver driver =new HtmlUnitDriver(true);`
I guess i can work around it (since my code is on production for other projects using WebDriver) and use HtmlUnitDriver but I have no idea how to use the executeScript to pass a url for the script

How can I inject this to my WebDriver? Thanks

Comment: More likely there is a versions mismatch. What are the Selenium, browser and driver versions you are using?

Comment: @Guy Dont think its a version issue. I am getting the same error on FF, but there at least the loading is completed ok. See updated post

Comment: There is an option for HtmlUnit to not stop on js errors (like browsers). Enable this.

Comment: @SkarosIlias The exception is thrown from the webdriver, it has nothing to do with the site. `htmlunit-driver 2.28` is old, from 2017. Try updating it https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases

Comment: Think also about updating to the latest version of selenium/htmlunit (HtmlUnit is currently at 2.35.0)

Comment: Thank you both. the newest version didnt help. I am still getting the same error. @RBRi can you tell me how i can enable the not stopping on error feature? cant find it.

Comment: remember that you are injecting the script into a page, not into the driver per say... if you inject before a .get, you will lose the script once the page loads.  The only thing that could execute before any page is loaded would be window calls.  (There is a Window, but there is no Document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize the WebClient used by the HtmlUnitDriver a bit. As default the option throwExceptionOnScriptError is true. But all the browsers are ignoring processing the javascrip if a (unhandled) exception occurs. If i got you right your page throws this exception also if running with the real browser; means you have to

1. swith of throwExceptionOnScriptError
2. talk to the page/js developer about code quality

Sample code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true) {
    @Override
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        return client;
    }
};
```

Comment: Great! thanks. that seems to be just what i needed. I just changed it a bit, from `new HtmlUnitDriver() {` to `new HtmlUnitDriver(true) {` in order to activate javaScript. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the hint have fixed my answer.